# What is the difference between the prepositions 'up' and 'onto', both indicating 'motion'?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositions, difference, grammaticality

We are all familiar with the the rhyme:

> *Jack and Jill went **up** the hill.*

The preposition 'up' describes *motion from a lower level to a higher level*. But the preposition 'onto' also describes 'motion'. Therefore, can we use the preposition 'onto' in place of 'up'?

> *Jack and Jill went **onto** the hill.*

Is it grammatically correct? If correct, is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: *Jack and Jill went onto the hill* is an extremely unlikely utterance, because ***onto*** refers to a (usually, *horizontal*) ***surface***. In that context, adverbially defining ***where*** they went, whereas ***...up** the hill* adverbially defines ***how*** they went (in an ***upward*** direction).

Answer (score 2):

*Up* shows direction of motion. You can go *up the hill* from anywhere on it, even from the very bottom.

*Onto* shows motion to a place that is on top of something. The motion itself does not need to be upward. You can parachute *onto a hill* from above.

Comment: Exactly as Colin says. You lift a cat up to place it onto a table.

Comment: @RonaldSole She lifted the cat up to place it on/ upon a table. Can we use on/ upon instead of onto here?

Comment: @Colin Fine, "you can parachute down a hill from above".  Even "you can parachute into a town from above".  Are these okay?

Comment: @SandipKumarMandal Yes, **on** and **upon** are alternatives in this context. No, you can't parachute down a hill (you can drive, walk, cycle, ride, fall etc down a hill.  But you can parachute on to a hill. And you can parachute into a town. To add **from above** is saying the obvious. You can't parachute from below .

Comment: @RonaldSole, Thank you. It's now clear.

Comment: To clarify further what Ronald says: _up_ and _down_ as **adverbs** refer solely to the direction of motion: _lift the cat up_, _parachute down_.  _Up_ and _down_ as **prepositions** refer to motion relatively upwards or downward _staying on or in_ the object. _Down the hill_ means _moving downward, staying on the hill_, which is why you cannot _parachute down the hill_.